# Excel workbook with macros using 50% CPU even when idle

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, cpu-usage

First:

- Using excel 2010, Win 7
- All additional add-ons have been disabled
- All spreadsheets have had the last used cell reduced to its minimum row, column value
- I have an old machine in today's standards, Dell Inspiron 6400, 1.73 GHz, 3.3 Gig ram

I have a spreadsheet that when open and active it uses at least 50% of the cpu even when idle.  If I then run other programs this has caused the computer to over heat and shut down.  I posted this problem on a different forum a few months ago and the end advice was, "Don't worry about it".  Well, I can no longer do this.  It's become a problem.

At first I thought it was any workbook with macros.  I have since convinced myself this is not the case.  I then thought it might be add-ons that I have add.  This isn't the case either.  I read to minimize the spreadsheets to their smallest size.  This didn't help.  This workbook has an auto-open which saves a backup, gathers some data off the internet and does some manipulations with that data. I totally removed this subroutine, and no effect.  Another thing to note is if I open another workbook, leaving this open too, and make this second workbook the active workbook, te cpu usage goes to nearly zero.  One last thing to note is I have several precursors to this "final version" of this workbook.  They all do not have this cpu problem.  Somewhere, somehow, I have added some code to this "final version" that is causing this problem.

I'm hoping someone can give me some clues as to what else to look for.  I will be comparing these old backups to the current version, but this is going to be the long way around.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you please provide some specifics of the macros causing that problem? Code snippets will be helpful. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Go to Data ► Connections ► Connections and Data ► Get External Data ► Existing Connections to see what you have there.

Comment: Jeeped - You hit the nail on the head.  There were hundreds.  I deleted all of them.  Problem solved.  Next question - Is there a way so that these don't accumulate? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Jeeped - I went back and did a little more cleanup.  Since my first post I was trying to solve the problem.  After restoring the workbook back to its original condition I checked the cpu usage.  It is zero most the time with an occasional bleep of 1%.  Thank you so much.  I owe you a beer!  My computer owes you 2 beers and 5 years more life.  Thanks

Comment: @Jeeped, it is an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Subject to my earlirt comment, when the Auto_Open macro ran everytime the workbook was opened, it created a new *connection* to its Internet data without discarding previous ones. These ancient connection should be listed Data ► Connections ► Connections and/or Data ► Get External Data ► Existing Connections.

As I do not have the full method and parameters of the internet connection created, I'll offer this sort `` event macro that will remove all connections whenever the workbook is closed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    With ThisWorkbook
        Dim cn As Object
        For Each cn In .Connections
            cn.Delete
        Next cn
        .Save
    End With
End Sub
```

That macro goes into the *ThisWorkbook* code sheet. Note that it also saves your workbook; if this is not wanted behavior, move the code to a Module sheet and change it to a public macro that can be manually run.

Comment: Jeeped - Thanks again.  I figured it out, but yours is prettier.  I did it with a do while statement.  It seems to me that I don't really need the Call Nuke_Connections statement and I probably won't include the .Save.  Thanks, you've been a big help, you really have

Comment: @awsmitty - Sorry about that! I tested that sub in a few configurations; one of which was to call a public sub that could also be run manually. I left that call line in but it is edited out now. Thanks for picking up on that.

Comment: Jeeped - I just wanted to say thanks again.  I just started downloading info from the web in say, around October of last year.  I had no idea these connections were accumulating. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @awsmitty - Thanks for taking the time to drop off this latest short note. It is always welcome news to hear such success stories.